# Why do I only get a function as a return value by using a fixture (from pytest) in a test script?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, python-unittest, fixtures

I want to write test functions for my code and decided to use pytest. I had a look into this tutorial: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-python-applications-with-pytest

My real code involves another script, written by me, so I made an example, which also creates the same problem, but does not rely on my other code.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def example():
    value = 10
    return value

def test_value(example):
    print(example)
    assert(example == 10)

test_value(example)
```

When I run my script with this toy example, the print returns a function:

<function example at 0x0391E540>

and the assertion fails.

If I try to call example() with the parenthesis, I get this:

Failed: Fixture "example_chunks" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.

I am sure, I am missing something important here, but searching google did not help me, which is why I hope somebody here can provide some assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove this line from your script

```py
test_value(example)
```

2. Run your script file with `pytest file.py`

Fixtures will be automatically resolved by pytest

In your example you run code directly and fixtures are just simple functions

Comment: A true beginners mistake it was. I figured as much. Thanks for the advice.